# Why won't you go in your home?

Tags: terraria

I am on the verge of building a mini metropolis in Terraria but no one is arriving? What do I need to do? I have a table chair and light source but nothing for the last hour. What do I need to do?

I tried going through the post that has been on here but still got nowhere. It was the wiki and that post that I tried to follow before (and that post that brought me to this site) Seems that only Josh wants to be helpful though

Comment: do you have a bed?

Comment: You've verified that it's acceptable housing?

Comment: I have a bed for me to teleport back to it I am on about NPC houses

Comment: The ones I had were 5 blocks tall but still nothing. Just tried 4 wide and 10 tall and seem to have worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have any followers move in, in Terraria. You need to have the following:

- A room or house 4 blocks high and 10 blocks wide
- A table
- A chair
- A lightsource

It's also worth noting :
*"Houses must not be located near Corruption or Crimson, and if those spread too close to an occupied House, the NPC living there may move out."*

Source: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC